# WebGL vertices array order

Tags: webgl

I've just read this mozilla WebGL tutorial and came upon a question
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context

I'm wondering why an array of positions for a simple square should be

```
const positions = [
    -1.0,  1.0, // 1 - top left
     1.0,  1.0, // 2 - top right
    -1.0, -1.0, // 3 - bottom left
     1.0, -1.0, // 4 - bottom right
];
```

instead of

```
const positions = [
    -1.0,  1.0, // 1 - top left
     1.0,  1.0, // 2 - top right
     1.0, -1.0, // 4 - bottom right
    -1.0, -1.0, // 3 - bottom left
];
```

which would make more sense to me.

In the first case (the correct one), it seems that the lines drawing the square from vertex to vertex should cross, but obviously it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using `TRIANGLE_STRIP` indexing in that example:

> Draws a series of triangles (three-sided polygons) using vertices v0,
>   v1, v2, then v2, v1, v3 (note the order), then v2, v3, v4, and so on.
>   The ordering is to ensure that the triangles are all drawn with the
>   same orientation so that the strip can correctly form part of a
>   surface.

*[Wikipedia - Triangle strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip#cite_ref-3)*